# Outlook mis-declaringn TIFFs as PNGs

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, images, png, tiff

I often receive emails with screenshots as inline images sent from Outlook/Office365 where the image is sent like this:

```
Content-Type: image/png; name="image001.png"
Content-Description: image001.png
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="image001.png"; size=442270;
    creation-date="███, ██ ██ 2021 ██:██:██ GMT";
    modification-date="███, ██ ███ 2021 ██:██:██ GMT"
Content-ID: <image001.png@████████.████████>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

TU0AKgAF58DLy8v/y8vL/8vLy//Ly8v/y8vL/8vLy//Ly8v/y8vL/8vLy//Ly8v/y8vL/8vLy//L
y8v/y8vL/8vLy//Ly8v/y8vL/8vLy//Ly8v/y8vL/8vLy//Ly8v/y8vL/8vLy//Ly8v/y8vL/8vL
...
```

The MIME type is declared to be PNG, but the base64 encoded content is TIFF (the first part of the base64 encoding `TU0AKg` decodes to the big endian TIFF magic number `4D 4D 00 2A`). This wrong encoding will cause some clients to display a broken image, specifically I tested:

- Thunderbird
- K-9
- Roundcube
- web client of web.de

These clients circumvent the problem:

- Outlook (desktop and web)
- Gmail web client

Could the cause be an Outlook misconfiguration on the part of the sender, or is Outlook just being the Internet Explorer of email, sending messages specially "optimized" for Outlook?

Comment: I haven't found related .png issue on my Outlook before, I may not know much about encoding, so how did you send/receive this png and track those encoding information?

Comment: @Jade The messages are sent from an Outlook desktop client. I listed some clients that show the problem in the question. The above code is an excerpt from the message's source code.

Comment: Most programs just use the file name to generate the mime type instead of checking the file content. If the user sends a PNG file it is sent as `image/png` mime type no matter what the content is. Therefore I would assume this is more a problem with file nameing than an Outlook problem. Outlook just uses the name the user has set.

Comment: @Robert There never was a physical file with any name or extension – the sender reports that it's pasted from the clipboard.

Comment: That could still mean that the data was saved as temporary file even if not visible to the user, because I don't think pasting image data via clipboard into an email is supported by Outlook, and even more I don't think that such pasted content would end up as TIFF image.